# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri"

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the problem codes

```
void _search(String query){
    String url = ("https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${query}&per_page=20&page=0");
    http.get(url)
        .then((response){
          print(response);
    })
    .catchError((err){
      print(err);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as the title says. You cannot assign a String where a Uri is expected.

Try as follows:

```
void _search(String query) {
  String url = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${query}&per_page=20&page=0"; 

  final uri = Uri.parse(url);

  http.get(uri)
      .then((response) {
             print(response);
           })
      .catchError((err) {
         print(err);
       });
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer, or even better: remove the question since it is a duplicate.